# Finding a sufficient statistic

Tags: distributions, self-study, sufficient-statistics

Consider an i.i.d. sample $(X_{1},\ldots, X_{n})$ where the $X_{i}$ have density
$f(x) = k \cdot \exp(−(x − θ)^4)$ with $x$ and $\theta$ real, obtain the sufficient statistic and its dimension. What does this example show? Is the statistic that you have found also complete?

Comment: The obvious thing to begin with is to use the Fisher-Neyman factorization theorem and expand the quartic. The components of $T(X)$ may be obtained by inspection.

Comment: @Glen_b  if i expand the quartic i get e^(ΣX^4-4θΣX^3+6θ^2ΣX^2-4θ^3ΣX+θ^4)

Comment: Sorry, that's almost - but not quite - correct. But it should be clear how to write a vector $T(X)$ times some vector function of $\theta$ to replicate almost all of that expanded expression.

Comment: yes, i get it. so, i think, the result is that T(X) is a joint sufficient statistics formed by (ΣX;ΣX^2;ΣX^3), it's dimension is 3, despite the dimension of θ is 1 @Glen_b