# Sufficient statistic with 4 dimensions

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference

I have an i.i.d. sample with this density:

$ f_\theta (x) = k * exp (- (x - \theta)^4 ) $

How can I obtain the sufficient statistic?

Is the statistic that I find also complete?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not an answer to your question but why do you think the sufficient statistics has to have 4 dimensions?

Comment: See the discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67639/finding-a-sufficient-statistic). Can you explain the context in which such a question arises (how for example, outside of a textbook question which specifies it, could you know that's the distribution of your sample)? If it is a study-related question, could you please include the `self-study` tag?

Comment: Hi, yes it is a textbook question, I'll add the tag, sorry. It asks if this statistic I find is also complete. With the factorization theorem, it seemed to be a quite complicated statistic for a sufficient one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the factorization theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) to solve this problem.  If you can factorize

$$f_\theta(\mathbf{x})=k\times \exp(-(x-\theta)^4)=h(x)g(\theta,\,T(x))$$

(which you can) then you can identify the sufficient statistic(s) as $T(x)$